# show second result for multiple records - MSSQL2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

I've got a query that displays the second result for one customer.
what i now need to do is show the second result for each customer in a particular list (for example 20 different customers).

how would i do this?
MS SQL2000 via SSMS 2005

current query for 1 customer is

```
SELECT TOP 1 link_to_client, call_ref
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 2 link_to_client, call_ref
    FROM calls WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE link_to_client IN ('G/1931')
        AND call_type = 'PM'
    ORDER BY call_ref DESC
) x
ORDER BY call_ref
```

thanks

Comment: any more suggestions guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [row_number()](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/ms186734.aspx) function, try something like this:

```
select
    link_to_client, call_ref 
from
    (
        select
            link_to_client, call_ref, 
            row_number() over (partition by link_to_client order by call_ref desc) n
        from 
            calls with (nolock) 
        where 
            link_to_client in ('G/1931') 
            and call_type = 'PM' 
    ) x
where
    n = 2 -- second result for every client
```

Comment: i get "'row_number' is not a recognized function name" also on this one

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
SELECT 
      link_to_client
    , call_ref
FROM (
    SELECT 
          link_to_client
        , call_ref
        , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY link_to_client ORDER BY call_ref DESC)
    FROM dbo.calls WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE link_to_client = 'G/1931'
        AND call_type = 'PM'
) x
WHERE x.rn = 2
```

Comment: i get "'row_number' is not a recognized function name" when i try that

Comment: On `SQL Server 2005` all works fine. Please provide your compatibility level.

Comment: if i knew how to tell you i would :)

Comment: i'm using SQL Server Management Studio (v9) to run the queries

Comment: Try this query - `SELECT [compatibility_level]
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id = DB_ID()`

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'sys.databases'.

Comment: You are connected to `SQL Server 2000` from `SSMS 2005`?

Comment: ah now you say that, i think that may be correct.
i don't have physical access to the server, so i might have been thinking about a different one when i said 2005 previously.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work in sqlserver 2000:

```
SELECT link_to_client, 
(
SELECT TOP 1 call_ref
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 2 link_to_client
    FROM calls WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE link_to_client = a.link_to_client
        AND call_type = 'PM'
    ORDER BY call_ref DESC
) x
ORDER BY call_ref
) call_ref
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT link_to_client
FROM calls WITH (NOLOCK)) a
```